# How do I write the flow definition for a function where the input is an object, and the output is mutated

Tags: javascript, flowtype

How do I write the flow definition for a function where the input is an object exact type, and the output is the object mutated with an added property?

Here is an [example](https://flow.org/try/#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-AFgDnI6EXGKlJypHm1cgAcgAUnBZDwxw8KlUMllxwBlFRyMc-PxA-2gyEohFSroAIRo1t6SnOdFF1h4THCOYVvD2QTAcN4AEkeDh40xovErhuFF5zAQkqGJM5tk+fJvlaKV-jWQFgQDAAxTh3AhHt3x4L8fyMBgkWw3DfyibEB1xFECReE4SWiCkqUoukR0ZFk2QY6EuUXBk+QFKwqBFMVuxRSVUCAA)

I have copy pasted the code from the example below in case the link expires.

```
/* @flow */
// README: select version 0.56.0

// this might be a backend response for example
type Person = {|
    firstName: string,
    lastName: string
|};


// this might be the backend response after it transformed?
type PersonDisplay = {
    ...Person,
    nameDisplay: string
};

const transform = (person: Person): PersonDisplay => {
  person.nameDisplay = `${person.firstName} + ${person.lastName}`;
  return person
};
```

Question: What is the best way of writing the flow definition for the 
 function `transform` where the input is an exact type and the output value is the object but with an extra property added?

```
const person: Person = {
  firstName: 'John',
  lastName: 'Smith'
}
transform(person);

// Below is my current solution
type PersonInExact = {|
    ...Person,
   nameDisplay?: string
|};

const transformFix = (person: PersonInExact): PersonInExact => {
  person.nameDisplay = `${person.firstName} + ${person.lastName}`;
  return person
};
```

Errors I am seeing

```
5: type Person = {|                 ^ object type. This type is incompatible with the expected return type of
17: const transform = (person:Person):PersonDisplay => {
                                      ^ object type
Property `nameDisplay` is incompatible:
17: const transform = (person:Person):PersonDisplay => {
                                      ^ property `nameDisplay`. Property not found in
5: type Person = {|                 ^ object type
18:   person.nameDisplay = `${person.firstName} + ${person.lastName}`;
             ^ property `nameDisplay`. Property not found in
5: type Person = {|                 ^ object type
```

Comment: Please paste the relevant contents of your example into your question. Links tend to expire over time, in which case your question wouldn't be useful to others.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you're mutation the input. You can do the following:

```
/* @flow */
type Person = {|
    firstName: string,
    lastName: string
|};

const transform = (person: Person): { ...Person, nameDisplay: string } => {
  // If you'd rather use Object.assign instead of spread syntax
  // return Object.assign({}, person, { nameDisplay: `${person.firstName} + ${person.lastName}` })
  return {
    ...person,
    nameDisplay: `${person.firstName} + ${person.lastName}`
  }
}
```

Otherwise it wouldn't even you don't even need the return from the function because the input would match what you were expecting.

Answer (score 0):

As @kalley pointed out, the error was in your mutation of person.

However, I felt it worth noting that there is another solution which maintains your `PersonDisplay` type which presumably you want to use elsewhere.  Also, whilst using spread on types is possible, you might also want to consider using [Intersection types](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/intersections/), as this demonstrates.

Because of the exact nature of `Person`, you'd need to use type casting via any to coerce Flow into accepting the literal creation of `PersonDisplay`.  This has the downside of removing Flow's type checking in the creation of the response, so you'd need to be careful to ensure that the returned type was as intended.

```
/* @flow */
// README: select version 0.56.0

type Person = {|
    firstName: string,
    lastName: string
|};

type PersonDisplay = Person & {
    nameDisplay: string
};

const transform = (person: Person): PersonDisplay => {
  // Original: error by mutating person
  /*
  person.nameDisplay = `${person.firstName} + ${person.lastName}`
  return person
  */

  // NB: Because of the exact nature of Person, either of the following
  // methods to create a PersonDisplay requires casting via any
  // (See https://flow.org/en/docs/types/casting/)

  // Solution 1: Object assign
  /*
  return ((Object.assign({}, person, {
    nameDisplay: [person.firstName,person.lastName].join(' ')
  }): any): PersonDisplay);
  */

  // Solution 2: Object spread
  return (({
    ...person,
    nameDisplay: [person.firstName,person.lastName].join(' ')
  }: any): PersonDisplay)

};

const person: Person = {firstName: 'john', lastName: 'smith'}
const forDisplay: PersonDisplay = transform(person)
```